# How to get id from html using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My code has been given below . Why i am getting undefined? Please help me out.

//HTML is here

```
 <input type="hidden" id="element_id">
```

//Jquery code is here

```
$('#student_update_form').on('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr("element_id");
        alert(id);

});
```

Comment: using `$(this)` here you are referring to `form` not your hidden input field .

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and how does your `form` looks like?

Comment: What exactly you want to get?

As per your code, you will get the value of "element_id" appended to the form. Describe what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: just

```
$('#element_id').attr('id')
```

To selects a single element with the given id attribute:

```
$('#id')
```

it equivalent to `document.getElementById()` in Javascript: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

To get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

```
.attr()
```

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

You get `undefined` because

- `$(this)` does not refer to `<input type="hidden" id="element_id">`, it refer to the form has `id='student_update_form'`
- and this form does not has an attribute named: `element_id`, so js return `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var id = $('#element_id').attr('id');
alert(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#student_update_form').on('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

        var id = $("#element_id").val();
        alert(id);

});
```

There's no need to use attr, you can use id directly.